# SQLAlchemy's with_polymorphic ignores discriminator

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a polymorphic loading from a joined inhereted table (I use Flask-Sqlalchemy).

```
class Sip(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primety_key=True)
    identity = db.Column(db.String(10))
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'sip', 'polymorphic_on': identity}

class Device(Sip):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sip.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'dev'}

class Line(Sip):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sip.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'line'}
```

I've got one Device object and one Line object. When I try to make such a query:

```
Sip.query.with_polymorphic(Device).all()
```

it returns all the objects

```
[<myapp.models.Device at 0x45cfc50>, <myapp.models.Line at 0x45cfa90>]
```

Same situation when I use Line as an argument for `with_polymorphic()`. Table "sip" contains all required identities, I can check it:

```
>> Sip.query.with_polymorphic(Device).all()[0].identity
>> u'dev'
>> Sip.query.with_polymorphic(Device).all()[1].identity
>> u'line'
```

I just can't figure what's going on. Everything's seems to be exactly like doc example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`with_polymorphic`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_polymorphic) **does not filter** objects by type, but only defines columns from which other tables to fetch during the initial query. So, if you do not use `with_polymorphic` in your query, and would like to get a value for an attribute of `Line` which is stored in `lines` table, SA will issue another `SQL` statement to fetch the attribute from the database.

Enable `echo=True` in the engine, and you will see the different SQL statements been generated depending on the `with_polymorphic` usage:

- no usage: only attributes from the `sips` table would be loaded during the query
- `with_polymorphic(Device)`: will load attributes for the `devices` table as well (using `LEFT JOIN`s)
- `with_polymorphic("*")`: will load attributes for all the sub-classes in the same query.

For more on the topic please read [Basic Control of Which Tables are Queried](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html#with-polymorphic).

Comment: Thank you so much. I've read the docs, but was too lazy to look into SQL statements, my bad. So, I use `Sip.query.with_polymorphic(Device).filter_by(identity='dev').all()` now.

Comment: Great! You can also use `Device.query.all()` to get only `Devices`?

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to get all the columns from `Device` and `Sip` at once, which, as much as I understand, `with_polymorphic()` does.